# How to initialize the redux-form with values from store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to load a Redux Form pre-populated with values from the store.

currently, I am able to populate the redux form with data directly from the reducer, but while submitting the form it only accepts the data for clickable elements to generate the payload.

However, I'm able to get the data from reducer to store. I need to initialize the redux form with store values.

Is there any best approach to initialize the form elements with the values from the store and submit the whole model as payload?

I am attaching the redux-form herewith.

**Redux Form:-**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

let InitializeFromStateForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        {/* <button type="button" onClick={() => load(data)}>Load Account</button> */}
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="first_Name"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="First Name"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="last_Name"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Last Name"
          />
        </div>
      </div>


      <div>
        <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Undo Changes
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

// Decorate with reduxForm(). It will read the initialValues prop provided by connect()
InitializeFromStateForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'initializeFromState', // a unique identifier for this form
})(InitializeFromStateForm);

// You have to connect() to any reducers that you wish to connect to yourself
InitializeFromStateForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: {'first_Name':'sunil','last_Name':'choudhary'}, // pull initial values from account reducer
  }),
//   { load: loadAccount }, // bind account loading action creator
)(InitializeFromStateForm);

export default InitializeFromStateForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `change` function makes it so easier... `change` function is used to bind the `Field` data using `name` property

Here is the example to do it

Suppose you get your data in `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  const { change } = nextProps
  change('first_Name', 'sunil')
  change('last_Name', 'choudhary')
}
```

you can find it more [here](https://redux-form.com/7.0.0/docs/api/props.md/#-code-change-field-string-value-any-function-code-)